# react-native-image-crop-picker javaPreCompileDebug FAILED

Tags: react-native

Created a new project in React-native 0.62.2

installed **react-native-image-crop-picker**

and followed all the post installation steps.

When I try to build using **npx react-native run-android**, it stuck at the steps below for a long time (approximately 3 ~ 4 min)

```
<============-> 94% EXECUTING [2m 48s]
> Transforming artifact ucrop-2.2.2-native.aar (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native) with JetifyTransform > ucrop-2.
> Transforming artifact ucrop-2.2.2-native.aar (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native) with JetifyTransform
```

After that it will fail with the following error message

```
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:javaPreCompileDebug FAILED
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, react-native and NPM is extremely buggy that, a small typo or installing a wrong package will get you to a point with no return. You just have to create another new project, copy all the files over and re-install a relevant packages. Since posting this post, I had re-init my project at least 3 times.